# If the electron wave is within the wavelength of visible spectrum can we see it human eye? What kind of device is used to detect electron waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

Is there any device to detect electron waves or as we can see the visible spectrum can we see the electron wave if it is within the visible spectrum with our human eye.

Comment: It must be stressed that "visible" is a classical electromagnetic wave. Electrons are individual quantum mechanical particles. The wavelength of light is seen as  energy transferred as a function of space and time (Poynting vector). The wavelength of the electron is seen in the *probability distribution* of finding an electron at (x,y,z,t) . The electron is a point quantum mechanical particle.

Answer (score 3):

No. We detect photons (light) by the way they travel through the transparent eye, hit rods or cones, and provide the energy needed to change the shape of light sensitive molecules ([rhodopsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodopsin) and cousins). The energy contained in visible photons ranges from about $1.7\operatorname{eV}$ ($750\operatorname{nm}$) to $3.3\operatorname{eV}$ ($380\operatorname{nm}$). If you give electrons the same wavelength range, you get energies of about $2.7\times 10^{-6} \operatorname{eV}$ to $1.0 \times 10^{-5}\operatorname{eV}$. Electrons of that energy would not be able to trigger the changes in the light sensitive proteins, let alone penetrate the eyes to get to the photo-receptors. Worse, human body temperature regularly jostles everything in it with energy of the level of $k_BT\approx 2.7 \times 10^{-2} \operatorname{eV}$, so the action of such low energy electrons would be completely undetectable from the constant heat fluctuations.

Even if you gave the electron the same kinetic energy as the photon, it is unlikely it would be able to penetrate to the retina to be seen.

If you gave the electron enough energy to penetrate to the retina, and you produced an intense enough beam of them, they would produce flashes of light in your vision. Astronauts outside of the Earth's magnetosphere experience just such a phenomenon from [cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_visual_phenomena). I've even heard that x-ray crystallographers used to use this phenomenon with light to help align the invisible x-ray beam back in the day. The rumor stated that they would put their heads in the beam and look for scintillation in their vision to find where the beam is. Suffice it to say, this practice caused a fair amount of premature blindness before they perfected better techniques.